# Docker container for hosting discord/telegram bots

Tags: web-apps, python, docker

I have own home server where apps are in docker containers. I want to host my own bots for discord/telegram (on python or making them on Golang later). I'd like to find some kind of dockered app where I can easily add start/stop, those bots, see their status, logs, setup autorestart and such things instead of starting them manually via ssh just somewhere in linux. Are there even such app for that kind of task?

Comment: Just use one container per bot and then the management you mentioned is easy. If you want to clump them together then any sort of basic scripting should work, depending on what exactly is needed.